# force:recordEdit Scenario

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, force-recordedit

I am using force:recordEdit tag in my lightning component. I have a boolean field (**Not present on layout**), which I want to mark as "true" before I click fire "e.recordSave" event.

Is there any workaround/trick to access the field.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot do this using fore:editrecord , I am confused on why force:createrecord has defaultFieldValues attribute but not the force:editrecord. Do you have to absolutely use  custom component,if not  this can be done by creating a new action and defaulting the values on edit/create of a specific object record. The only headache is that you need to create object specific actions and prepopulate the fields.https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=predefined_field_values.htm&type=0